# If $y_t$ and $x_t$ are cointegrated, then are $y_t$ and $x_{t-d}$ also cointegrated?

Tags: cointegration, unit-root, lags, random-walk

Assume that $x_t, y_t$ are $I(1)$ series which have a common stochastic trend $u_t = u_{t-1}+e_t$. Particularly, consider the following DGP

\begin{align}
y_t&=\alpha_y+u_t+a_t \tag{1} \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
x_t&=\alpha_x+u_t+b_t \tag{2} \\
\end{align}

Here $a_t, b_t$ are independent white noise processes.

Substituting $u_t$ from $(2)$ in $(1)$, we get:

\begin{align}
y_t &= \beta_0 + x_t+\mu_t \tag{3}\\
\text{where  } \beta_0 &\equiv \alpha_y-\alpha_x; \text{ and} \\
\mu_t &\equiv a_t-b_t
\end{align}

Based on $(3)$, $x_t$ and $y_t$ are cointegrated (is this correct?). Now consider an alternate formulation:

From $(2)$ we have that:
\begin{align}
\Delta x_t &= \Delta u_t+\Delta b_t \\
\implies x_t &= x_{t-1} + \nu_t \tag{4}\\
\text{where } \nu_t &\equiv e_t + \Delta b_t
\end{align}

substituting $(4)$ in $(3)$, we get:

\begin{align}
y_t &= \beta_0+x_{t-1}+\eta_t \tag{5}\\
\text{where } \eta_t &\equiv a_t-b_{t-1}+e_t
\end{align}

Does equation (5) means that $x_{t-1}$ and $y_t$ are cointegrated (or that cointegration tests would fail to reject the null of co-integration)?

This can be extended to more lags of course but the variance of error term in long-term equation will keep increasing with lags. Clearly there is some fundamental gap in my understanding here but I actually getting such results for some series.

Comment: Yes indeed if $x_t$  is $I(1)$ then $x_t -x_{t-d} $ is stationary $I(0)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your title question: Yes, if $y_t$ and $x_t$ are cointegrated, then $y_t$ and $x_{t-d}$ are also cointegrated.

I think you got the intuition right:

- $y_t$ and $x_t$ are cointegrated and thus share a common stochastic trend.
- $x_t-x_{t-d}$ is a $d$-element sum of I(0) and thus still I(0).
- subtracting $x_t-x_{t-d}$ (which is I(0)) from $x_t$ (which is I(1)) yields $x_{t-d}$ which still has the same stochastic trend as $x_t$ because $x_t-x_{t-d}$ is merely I(0).
- Therefore, $y_t$ and $x_{t-d}$ are cointegrated.

Comment: Thanks! So couple of doubts: (1) Perhaps naive, but how does showing that $x_{t-d}$ is I(0) prove that $y_t$ and $x_{t-d}$ are cointegrated? (2) Would it be true for all $d$? Intuitively, I think that as we increase $d$ the additional sum of errors ($e_{t-d+1}$ to $e_t$) that are part of $y_t$ but not $x_{t-d}$ might start creating some problems in testing for cointegration. But if so, that would mean that the variance of white noise terms of $y_t$ and $x_t$ (relative to variance of white noise of the underlying stochastic trend ($e_t$) has influence on cointegration test

Comment: @Dayne, **1.** $x_{t-d}$ is not I(0), it is the same as $x_t$ which is I(1). **2.** Yes, as long as $d$ is finite and fixed. (You could analyze some sort of asymptotics when $d$ is growing, that would be another matter.) Regarding the power of cointegration tests, you are right, large $d$ would reduce test power, and this would be mostly felt in small samples. I agree about the variance, too.

Comment: terribly sorry about the mistake in (1). I meant, how does the fact that $x_t-x_{t-d}$ is I(0) sufficient to claim that $y_t$ and $x_{t-d}$ are cointegrated. And thanks again about answer to (2).

Comment: @Dayne, we know that I(0)+I(0)=I(0) in terms of orders of integration. So if you add an I(0) series to another I(0) series, you get an I(0) series. We also know that for cointegrated series, there is a linear combination which is I(0). If you add an additional I(0) series, the result is still I(0). So if we add an I(0) series of $x_t-x_{t-d}$ to the I(0) series $y_t-x_t$, we still get an I(0) series. Since both $y_t$ and $x_t$ are I(1), we get cointegration by definition.

Comment: That was pretty straight forward, which embarrassingly I failed to notice. Thanks again.

Comment: Unrelated to this, I have seen a number of your answers here on cointegration. I asked another question yesterday. If you do get time and consider the question worthy, please consider answering it: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/505811/interpretation-of-intercept-term-in-ecm

Comment: @Dayne, it sometimes looks straightforward after one has been pondering a topic for a long time, not before. I had thought about the question earlier, so I found it easy. But it is a great question!

Comment: @Dayne, I +1'ed your other question yesterday already but was too lazy/tired to attempt answering it.

Comment: :) Well I am hopeful now that sooner or later it will be answered.

Comment: @RichardHardy I don't think it is true that I(0) + I(0) = I(0). See here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/337636/is-stationarity-preserved-under-a-linear-combination.

Comment: @Student, you may be right, though I am not entirely sure. I(0) is not exactly the same as stationary, and its definition seems to vary across sources; see [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405907). I suppose if neither $x_t$ nor $y_t$ has a unit root, none of their linear combinations will. In that sense I(0)+I(0) cannot produce I(1). However, I would be curious to learn more about the subtleties around the validity of I(0)+I(0)=I(0).

Comment: @Student, intuitively, I find the following informal definition (cited in Davidson ["When is a time series I(0)?"](https://people.exeter.ac.uk/jehd201/WhenisI0.pdf) (2009)) appealing: *A finite (non-zero) variance stochastic process which does not accumulate past errors is said to be integrated of order zero* (Hendry 1995, p. 43).